# What is my error, how can I make this code run correctly?

Tags: java

It says "reached the end of paraphrasing" for the error on the left. It also seems has an error when run.

```
class recursion {

    public void mystery7(int n) {
        if(n <= 0) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        else if (n % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.print("(");
            mystery7(n - 1);
            System.out.print("(");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("[");
            mystery7(n - 1);
            System.out.print("]");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It is best to paste the code, not the photograph.

Comment: Also, we tend to try not to do your homework for you.

Comment: Hello, I have fixed and pasted it. And the code is simply named as such, I will change the code then.

Comment: Why is the question tagged as `python`?

Comment: This is java not the python

Comment: You broke the formatting. Just paste the code in, mark it and click the `{}` button.

Comment: Are you trying to access a non-static method with a static call?

Comment: @KlausD. I have fixed the issue, my apologies :(

Comment: Formatting still looks broken to me.  (Or if it isn't the formatting, then it is your Java style.)

Comment: Now there are no compilation errors.  But you won't be able to run it because there is no `public static void main(String[] args) {...}` method in the class.

Comment: @StephenC When that is changed as you suggested, it gives the errors "cannot find symbol" four times

Comment: I think your issue is the second `System.out.print("(");` in the `else if` clause. Should be printing a close-paren rather than an open-paren, no? How is this code being run, and where does the error come from? (I suspect in a testing program, and that this is your code producing the wrong output, rather than a Java error)

Comment: @jrchief test my answer, then let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: @jrchief - So your problem was apparently trying to run a class that didn't have a "static main()".  Doh!  Please "upvote" and "accept" Monstarules' response below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea if this is what you're looking for, but I assume it is?

```java
class recursion {
  public static void mystery7(int n) {
    
    if(n <= 0) {
      System.out.print("*");
    
    }
    else if (n % 2 == 0) {  
    System.out.print("(");  
    mystery7(n - 1);
    System.out.print(")");
   }
   else {
    System.out.print("[");
    mystery7(n - 1);  
    System.out.print("]");
    }
  }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // this is just an example number
    recursion.mystery7(5);
  }
}
```

My guess is that you were trying to call the method without declaring it static or properly referencing it. What I did was change the second open parenthesis to a closed parenthesis, and declared the method static since it did not look as if you wanted a constructor to implement the method.

What this does is print a bracket for every odd number encountered and a parenthesis for every even number encountered and then closes them after the asterisk is reached. I just tested it with multiple numbers and it should work fine for you.

Comment: When I run this, it still gives me this error "Error: Main method not found in class recursion, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application" but  I am guessing this might be that my compiler is doing this incorrectly. This does seem to encompass my question perfectly though.

Comment: @jrchief I mean, that runs fine on Repl, in Netbeans, and in IntelliJ. I'm not entirely sure what you're using. Can you edit this post further with your compiler information, as well as the number of files you are using to run this program? I need to see the whole overall code, not just the recursion class.

Comment: I got it to work on my side, the compiling program I was using for my code was in fact doing this incorrectly, thank you very much for the help for the help.

Comment: I am glad I could help. If this was the answer, feel free to mark it as such!

Comment: @jrchief - So your problem was apparently trying to run a class that didn't have a "static main()". Doh! Please "upvote" and "accept" Monstarules' response below!